# Telerik control layout issues - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: telerik, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 on my machine along side 2012.  We have several web applications (ASP.NET and MVC) that utilize Telerik controls.  Today I noticed accordion controls (expanders) are fully expanded and the contents within are stacked one on top of the other.  Additionally, some of the container controls are skewed.  Has anyone run into this same issue?  Upgrading to the latest Telerik tools has not helped.  However, running the same application in Visual Studio 2012 works as expected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After one more google attempt I found this line (added to the web.config) to be the fix I was looking for:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Visual Studio 2013 inserts some markup in every page to enhance runtime debugging, the line above prevents that markup from being added.