# Asp.Net Telerik RadGrid : Data does not render in tabular format

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have an ASP.NET Telerik RadGrid control declared as below. The first column is a templated column which has checkboxes for each row. I observe that whenever I use the html checkbox input control the grid is rendered properly using the WebBlue skin. However, if I use an Asp.Net server side checkbox control then the data is rendered without the grid/table. (Screenshots attached). Now I need to use the server side controls to be able to use them in my server side functionality. I would really appreciate if someone is able to figure the solution for this bug.

```
        <telerik:RadGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ID="FxTransactionGrid" AllowFilteringByColumn="false"
            AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="false" runat="server" GridLines="None" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
            Skin="WebBlue" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" AlternatingItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
            SortingSettings-EnableSkinSortStyles="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            OnItemCommand="FxTransactionGrid_ItemCommand" Font-Names="veranda" 
            >
            <MasterTableView GroupLoadMode="Client" TableLayout="Auto" DataKeyNames="ExecRate, High, Low, SlippageVSMid,SlippageVSWMCO,ApprovedBy,Mt_ref, Warning" 

            Font-Size="Smaller" AllowMultiColumnSorting="true">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CheckBox" ItemStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <input id="headerCheckBox" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAllRows(this);" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%--<input id="rowCheckBox" type="checkbox" />--%>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="rowCheckBox" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

               ...other columns....
       </telerik:RadGrid>
```

[image: Grid with Server-side CheckBox control]

[image: Grid with HTML CheckBox Input control]

Comment: Follow this link. It should help fix your issue. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915504/telerik-control-layout-issues-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915504/telerik-control-layout-issues-visual-studio-2013) 
I think this should resolve the issue you are facing. the problem is VS2013.